# Can't WebSocket multi-task in WebGL?

Tags: websocket, solana, unity-webgl

Can't WebSocket multi-task in WebGL?

Unity Version : 2022.1.23f1

I am using packages https://github.com/jirihybek/unity-websocket-webgl package.
and https://github.com/magicblock-labs/Solana.Unity-SDK package.

i am using solana adapter to communicate with my wallet and create a separate c# websocket server to create a game server.

the problem is that i can't connect to the c# server after connecting my solana wallet.
communication with c# works fine normally if i don't connect solana wallet.

Can't WebSocket multi-task in WebGL?

Thanks a lot

it was confirmed that each unit test was operating normally.

Add:
if i connect my solana wallet, the websocket handshake not work with the c# game server.

Receive:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5589
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: http://localhost:10672
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ko-KR,ko;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Sec-WebSocket-Key: hfKK4OpYoiUP8V2s59KU7Q==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
```

Send Message:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: shauwsrpKMJX7NARe3KvYnYf9l0=
```